# Vertical equivalent of \mathclap?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting

Is there a vertical equivalent of `\mathclap`, i.e. a command that will ,,crush`` part of a formula to height zero, allowing better alignment with other parts of the same formula?

To illustrate what I want to achieve, consider the following (largely made-up) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        A \begin{pmatrix}
            x \\ y \\ z
        \end{pmatrix} 
        & = 
        u \cdot \left( \text{some rather long term} \right) \\
        & = 
        v \cdot \left( \text{another rather long term} \right) \\
        & = 
        w \cdot \left( \text{a third rather long term} \right)
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

whereas would I'd *like to achieve* is

[image]

(I personally think that's more readable; YMMV, of course).

Is this possible, and if so, how? I've done some superficial research but came up empty-handed.

Comment: `\smash`? `amsmath` extends it to `\smash[b]`, `\smash[t]`, default is `\smash[tb]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The vertical equivalent of `\mathclap{...}` is `\smash{...}`. `\smash` is available in both PlainTeX and LaTeX.

If you load the `amsmath` package, you will also get `\smash[b]{...}` and `\smash[t]{...}`. These commands set the depth and height of their arguments to zero. (One could say that they're somewhat similar in function to `\mathrlap` and `\mathllap`. But not perfectly equivalent, for sure.)

For the case of your sample code, then, you will want to replace

```
A \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}
```

with

```
A \smash[b]{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.