# Add dots at the end of table without taking up space

Tags: tables

I want to add dots at the end of a table like this without taking up space from the table, so just an open-ended table with dots at the end, with the dots taking up no space, what I have so far is this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&1&O \\
\hline
&\vdots&
\end{array}
```

[image]

This is the expected output closest to I can represent it.
[image]

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23845 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515964.

Comment: I recommend providing a complete example (that can be compiled) and a drawing/screenshot/rendering of the expected output.

Comment: I haven't been able to find an example of the expected output yet, I will keep searching and let you know if I find one.

Comment: I drew one with microsoft paint, it's not very good but it get's the idea across :)

Comment: @cabbagedude What you mean by `taking no space` is not completely clear to me. Please have a look at my proposal and criticize it, if this not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this suit you?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&1&0 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\smash{\vdots}}\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Remove the `\smash`to increase space, if wished.

[image]

Comment: You can use `\raisebox{-2ex}[0pt][0pt]{\huge$\vdots$}` to overlap the bottom.  The tabular will always produce an edge `\arraystretch\baselineskip` tall.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes. Yet, I am waiting for a clarification from the OP.

Comment: Yes, but without the lines at the bottom on the sides so that they don't include the dots, the picture was a little unclear, sorry.

Comment: @cabbagedude See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the excellent package `tabularray`.
The `X`, `Y`, `Z` denotes the three last lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={|c|c|c|},
    vlines={Z}{dashed},
    hline{1-Y},
  }
  1&1&0 \\
  0&1&1 \\
  &&
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more compact version:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={ccc},
    % spec of the lines 1 to Y
    rowsep=1pt,
    hline{1-Y},
    vlines={1-Y}{solid},
    % spec of the last (Z) line
    vlines={Z}{dashed},
    row{Z}={abovesep=0pt,belowsep=0pt},
  }
  1&1&0 \\
  0&1&1 \\
  &&
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\omit` TeX primitive omits the declared table mask in the given item in the table (i.e. in the `\halign` primitive). Your example can look like this:

```
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&1&O \\
\hline
\omit&\omit\hfil\vdots\hfil&\omit
\end{array}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start based on [Vertical equivalent of \mathclap?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515964). I do not fully understand the question so I am pretty sure that you are not 100 % happy with this :).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 \\\hline
&\smash[t]{\vdots}&
\end{array}   
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]